# Which domain called the script?

Tags: php, apache

I have some scripts that really need to be secured. So I was thinking, is there a way to find out which domain called the script?

Answer (score 1):

Look through the [`$_SERVER`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) variable and you will see all the information you need.

`$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']` and `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` may be of use to you.

Answer (score 0):

`$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` will have the domain name.

Answer (score 0):

`$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` will contain the host or virtual host under which the script is running.

`$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` contains the contents of the Host: header from the current request, if there is one.

Please see [Chris Shiflett's extended explanation](http://shiflett.org/blog/2006/mar/server-name-versus-http-host) for a detailed comparison of the two.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably a lot of ways to do this.. But I would setup logging in the script and report back with

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']
```

And here is a helpful page for more information..

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia lists a number of defences against [cross site request forgery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) attacks.